# End Service if already running on Mac

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to create an *Automator* service that allows me to speak selected text.

I want to be able to use a keyboard shortcut, however, I also want to use a keyboard shortcut to end the service before it finishes.

I cannot figure out how to make the service stop once started running.

Here is my applescript code in *Automator*:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    say input using "Alex" speaking rate 400

    return input
end run
```

I know you can speak text in system prefs. But it maxes out at 300 wpm. I need this to do more than 300. Hence the Automator service.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way should be to *start saying nothing.*

```
say "" stopping current speech true
```

If executed it will stop the current say output.

Comment: I tried this first and it doesn't stop the current speech. All it does is determine when the new phase is spoken. For example when false the new speech waits until the current speech ends before speaking. When true it doesn't wait. But in either case it doesn't stop the current speech.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the dictionary lied :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by getting the pid of the service, just write the pid to a temporary file.

When you want to stop the speaking, the script get the pid in the temporary file to quit this process ID.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set tFile to POSIX path of (path to temporary items as text) & "__auto_Runner_Speak_text__last_Pid__.txt"
    try
        set lastPid to word 1 of (read tFile) -- get the pid of the last speak text
        if lastPid is not "" then
            set tPids to words of (do shell script "/bin/ps -Axcro pid,command | sed -n '/Automator Runner/s/^ \\([0-9]*\\).*/\\1/p'")
            if lastPid is in tPids then
                do shell script "echo '' > " & (quoted form of tFile) & ";/bin/kill " & lastPid & " > /dev/null 2>&1 &" -- empty the file and stop the speaking
                return -- quit this service
            end if
        end if
    end try
    do shell script "echo $PPID > " & quoted form of tFile -- write the PID of this workflow to the temp file
    say input using "Alex" speaking rate 400
    do shell script "echo '' > " & quoted form of tFile -- remove the PID of this workflow in the temp file
end run
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically you'll have to kill the speech synthesis process...

```
try
    set thePID to word 1 of (do shell script "/bin/ps -Axcro pid,command | grep speechsynthesis")
    do shell script "kill -15 " & thePID
end try
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I make it speak if no process is running, and kill if one is already running? I guess i'm asking if this try block returns anything I could use in an if statement.

Comment: I want one keyboard command to either start or stop the speaking.

Comment: I understand what you want. Unfortunately when you kill the process it doesn't actually end the process. The speech will stop but the process continues to run. As such checking if the process is present won't tell you if some speech is happening. I can't think of a way to know if speech is ongoing.